# Statistical significance test of FindCluster

Tags: probability-or-statistics, cluster-analysis

I have a list of vectors which could be roughly divided into two clusters. The list is huge so I have to use `RandomChoice[list, 20000]` to speed up the calculation. But some vectors would oscillate between two clusters when taking different samples of the original huge list. So I would like to know how well a vector fits in its cluster. I added `Method->{Automatic, "SignificanceTest" -> "Silhouette"}`, but nothing seems to be happening. Is there a way to get a return of some kind of "confidence value" for each vector? Thanks!

---

My code:

```
clusters = FindClusters[answers -> Range[150],  DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance, Method -> {Automatic, "SignificanceTest" -> "Silhouette"}]
```

Where `answers` is the transpose of the said list, i.e. a 150 x 20000 table.

Comment: Are you using `FindClusters`?

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes!

Comment: According to the documentation, `FindClusters` only accepts two `Method` options, `"Agglomerate"` or`"Optimize"`, with no sub-options.

Comment: @2012rcampion check tutorial/PartitioningDataIntoClusters, it mentioned significance test at the end

Comment: Yes, I just saw [that tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PartitioningDataIntoClusters.html).  (Inconsistent docs are no good!)  From that tutorial, it looks like the `"SignificanceTest"` option changes what `FindClusters` uses internally to decide if a cluster *as a whole* is significant.  It provides no way to extract this data, and I don't think it would apply to individual data points anyway.

Comment: Wait, so you have `answers = Transpose@RandomChoice[list, 20000]`?  Aren't you then clustering the dimensions, not the individual data points?  Is your data really 150-dimensional?

Comment: An estimate for the confidence is the ratio of its distances to the two cluster centers.

Comment: @2012rcampion Yes, that's a result of a psychological test consisting of 150 questions. I'm curious how the answers are related to each other. I know nothing about the math behind cluster analysis or SST, and it seems that it's not a built-in feature of Mathematica. So I may as well just wait to see if anyone has done this before.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks, I'll try that! Could this estimate be used in weighted average? Or is it just intended for ordinal comparison?

Comment: I might suggest [PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) instead of cluster analysis.  Use `SingularValueDecomposition` after balancing your data (e.g. turn `True`/`False` to `+1`/`-1`, or `1 ... 5` to `-2 ... +2`).